# Unable to connect to a cluster from GridDB CLI

Tags: griddb

I've installed GridDB on my PC using Docker containers by following the installation
documentation. I successfully started the Docker image, and the GridDB container is running. I
verified the GridDB status and confirmed that the database is up and running. I configured the
node and cluster settings using the GridDB CLI, set up a user for admin authentication, and
attempted to connect to the cluster. However, I encountered an error during the connection
process.

I want to access the Grid DB cluster via GridDB CLI.

Error Message

D20307: An unexpected error occurred while attempting to connect. msg=[(NoSQL) 172.18.0.2:10040, [145028:JC_BAD_CONNECTION] Failover timed out (trialCount-30, failureMillis-30016, timeoutMillis-30000, reason-[145028:JC_BAD_CONNECTION] Faile d to update by notification (address-/172.18.0.2:10040, reason-Not a multicast address), historySize-31, historyOfTop10( trial, millisFromInitial, millisFromPrev, reason)-[(11, 9006, 1002, [145028:JC_BAD_CONNECTION] Failed to update by notif ication (address-/172.18.0.2:10040, reason-Not a multicast address)), (15, 13008, 1001, [145028:JC_BAD_CONNECTION] Faile d to update by notification (address=/172.18.0.2:10040, reason-Not a multicast address)), (16, 14009, 1001, [145028:JC B AD_CONNECTION] Failed to update by notification (address-/172.18.0.2:10040, reason-Not a multicast address)), (19, 17018 1001, [145028:JC_BAD_CONNECTION] Failed to update by notification (address-/172.18.0.2:10040, reason-Not a multicast a ddress)), (20, 18011, 1001, [145028:JC_BAD_CONNECTION] Failed to update by notification (address-/172.18.0.2:10040, reas on-Not a multicast address)), (22, 20012, 1001, [145028:JC_BAD_CONNECTION] Failed to update by notification (address-/17 2.18.0.2:10040, reason-Not a multicast address)), (25, 23013, 1001, [145028:JC_BAD_CONNECTION] Failed to update by notif ication (address-/172.18.0.2:10840, reason-Not a multicast address)), (28, 26014, 1001, [145028:JC_BAD_CONNECTION] Faile d to update by notification (address=/172.18.0.2:10040, reason-Not a multicast address)), (30, 28015, 1001, [145028:JC B AD_CONNECTION] Failed to update by notification (address-/172.18.0.2:10048, reason-Not a multicast address)), (31, 29015 1000, [145028:JC_BAD_CONNECTION] Failed to update by notification (address-/172.18.0.2:10040, reason-Not a multicast a ddress))])]

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmcHU.jpg)